# Shiny's RadioButton selection values not properly stored in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I am developing a questionnaire in Shiny which collects some user data using RadioButtons and produces a visualization based on the values that the user selects.

I am trying to store the selection values of my Radio Buttons in a MySQL database hosted on Amazon AWS. I have followed Dean Attali's [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#sqlite) to make it work.

Everything works fine, except that the selection values from my radio buttons are not properly inserted in the database. I am trying to store all these values as "TEXT" type in the MySQL database.

Following is the code that I am using.

Let's assume that I have a `ui.R` where I define 3 `radioButtons` called `dt_ds_q1`, `dt_ds_q2`, and `dt_ds_q3`. Depending on user selection, these `radioButtons` provide a value of `0` or `1`.

Following is the snipped from `server.R` which I am using for INSERTING in the database:

```
# Define the fields that need to be saved.
fields <- c("dt_ds_q1", "dt_ds_q2", "dt_ds_q3")

# Function for Saving Data on MySQL.
saveDataMySQL <- function(data, unique_id, session_id) {
    # Connect to the database
    db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), 
                    dbname = databaseName, 
                    host = options()$mysql$host, 
                    port = options()$mysql$port, 
                    user = options()$mysql$user, 
                    password = options()$mysql$password)
    
    # Concatenating UniqueID, SessionID, and Timestamp
    data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
    dt <- data %>% add_column(unique_id = unique_id, 
                             session_id = session_id,
                             timestamp = Sys.time())
    
    # Construct the update query by looping over the data fields
    query <- sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')",
        table, 
        paste(names(dt), collapse = ", "),
        paste(dt, collapse = "', '")
    )
    
    # Submit the update query and disconnect
    dbGetQuery(db, query)
    dbDisconnect(db)
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# Get form data from questionnaire
    formData <- reactive({
        data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
        data
    })

# Save data when someone clicks on the navbar title.
observeEvent({
        input$ati == "NAVBARNAME"
    },
                 saveDataMySQL(formData(), unique.id(), session.id()))
})
```

The output that I am getting is shown in the following image.

[Screenshot of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLF2F.png)

However, the desired input should have either a value of 1 OR 0.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was unnecessarily converting the list `formData()` to `data.frame` in the definition of the function `saveDataMySQL()`. Following is the updated code snipped which solved my problem (within the definition of `saveDataMySQL()` method:

```
# Adding unique ID, session ID and timestamp to list
    data <- c(data, unique_id, session_id, Sys.time())
    
    # Construct the update query by looping over the data fields
    query <- sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')",
        table, 
        paste(fields_all, collapse = ", "),
        paste(dt, collapse = "', '")
    )
```

where, `fields_all` is a list of column names, which I explicitly defined as:

```
fields_all = c("dt_ds_q1", "dt_ds_q2", "dt_ds_q3", "unique_id", "session_id", "timestamp")
```